# C:\Users\" + System.Environment.UserName + "FOLDER"

Tags: vb.net

So I need help with that code `C:\Users\" + System.Environment.UserName + "FOLDER"` There's `System.Environment.UserName` It only takes Logged in user, but I want it's gonna try ALL these folders in that Users.

Comment: Could you please state more clearly what you're trying to accomplish? It's pretty vague right now.

Comment: [This article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) should help you.

Comment: Right now that System.Environment.UserName takes only logged in UserName. But I want there something else ( not that System.Environment.UserName ). I want something what takes ALL folders inside the Users and then open specific folder there....

Comment: your app will not have access to *ALL folders inside the Users* so it is pointless

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)` to get the user's folder.

If you're going to try to look inside each user's folder, you probably won't be able to do that, since unless your program is running with administrator rights, only the profile for the user the application is running as will be available.